# how to append a list<T> object to another

Tags: c++, list, stl

in C++, I have two `list<T>` objects `A` and `B` and I want to add all the members of `B` to the end of `A`. I've searched a few different sources and haven't found a simple solution (e.i. `A.append(B);`) and this surprises me a bit.

*What is the best way to do this?*

As it happens, I don't care about B after this (it gets deleted in the very next line) so if there is a way to leverage that for better perf I'm also interested in that.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

If you want to append *copies of items* in B, you can do:

```
a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

If you want to *move items* of B to the end of A (emptying B at the same time), you can do:

```
a.splice(a.end(), b);
```

In your situation splicing would be better, since it just involves adjusting a couple of pointers in the linked lists.

Comment: +1. So right. If it could  have been so easy and efficient to "slice" maps and sets...

Comment: Are either of these operations O(1)?

Comment: I guess splice should be O(1) for the case above.

Comment: It is O(1) for `a.splice(a.end(), b)` and `a.splice(a.end(), b, it_b_start)`, but is O(n) for `a.splice(a.end(), b, it_b_start, it_b_end)`.

Comment: Is this method atomic? can I use it in a parallel environment?

Comment: @hkBattousai, interesting part about process scheduler, however I could use more info on that specific part, perhaps you could provide a link with more detail on why it is O(1) and O(n) ?

Comment: Why, o why, couldn't STL just support a.append(b)?

Answer (score -3):

one example using boost

```
std::list<T> A; // object A is a list containing T structure
std::list<T> B; // object B is a list containing T structure

// append list B to list A
BOOST_FOREACH(auto &listElement, B) { A.push_back( listElement ); }
```