# Append List to another list

Tags: c++, list, append

I have a large `list<pair<T, T>>`. To speed up my program i want to use different threads to fill up lists and then just connect them to 1 large list.

I found this solution: [Basically same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449703/how-to-append-a-listt-object-to-another)

To test this solution, I created 2 lists with 2mio elements each and connected them like said.

```
list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);
```

But this operation lasts a **few seconds** and this seems a bit long for me to just adjust a few pointers.

So what is the correct way to connect 2 lists??

EDIT:

```
cout << "Filling matrix... ";
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    list1.push_back(make_pair(i, false));
    list2.push_back(make_pair(i, false));
}
cout << "OK" << endl;

cout << "Merging lists... ";
clock_t begin = clock();

list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);

clock_t end = clock();
cout << "OK" << endl;
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout << "Time: " << elapsed_secs << endl;
```

Output:

> Filling matrix... OK
>   Merging lists... OK
>   Time: 4.54

Comment: Just tried it on my machine, and it's lightning fast. How did you measure performance?

Comment: This operation is supposed to have constant complexity... The code in your question __is__ the correct way of doing this.

Comment: clock_t begin = clock();
list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);
clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
It takes for me about 4.5 sec

Comment: What implementation are you using? Can you post a simplified test suite in your question that shows the time that you are getting? (Including initializing `gMatrix`)

Comment: I get `Time: 1e-06`. Must be something with your compiler settings.

Comment: I used VS2012. Now i tried C::B and it's working perfect.